# Which Custom Workout is Selected on miCoach Pacer?

Tags: micoach

I set all of my current running program up in my miCoach Pacer. I had just been running in free mode prior to today, the only workout I had done that wasn't in free mode was my initial assessment workout. When I hit the workout selection button it just says custom workout and how long the custom workout is. How do I know which one is selected?

I pushed the button a couple times to see if it would give me any other information. It turns out that all my custom workouts for the next ~2 weeks are 1 hour 10 minutes, and so I ended up selecting one that was over a week ahead of where I should have been, which was a much more difficult workout, and I only finished a little less than half of it because of the intensity.

Is there a better way to identify them in the web interface so I can tell which is which, or is there a way to get the Pacer to identify them better?

Comment: I could try and test it as soon as I have finished my program. Don't want to go deleting stuff with 2 more to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested running with three different Custom Workouts scheduled right before my Assessment Workout:

[image]

It cycled through the four workouts in the order they are scheduled. They were described by how many different Zones it had, it's color and total duration. Which probably gives problems with your C210k program, because they all have nearly the same amount of intervals, the same intensity, only the ratio between the length of the intervals is different. Sadly, that information isn't included!

The best work around is to turn on the Pacer, click on the Select Workout button **once** and then start your Workout. That way it will always select the workout that's first on the schedule. Are you unsure if you clicked once, turn it off and back on to try again.

Alternatively, pick one of the workouts from MiCoach itself that resembles C210k as much as possible.